# true or false test when knowing absolutely nothing

Tags: combinatorics

I have to answer a true-or-false test, where each question has probability 0.5 to be true. The bad news is that I don't have the faintest idea of the answers to the questions; the good news is that I can repeat the test until I manage to get all answers correct. At the end of each try, I will know how many questions I got right.

If the test is composed by a single question, I can pass it in at most two tries. With two questions, three tries may be needed: if my first attempt gets one right answer, I don't know which one is. I computed the result for 3 and 4 questions, and I obtained that I may need 4 or 5 tries respectively.

A pattern seems to reveal, but I am not really sure it is the right one. After all, when the number of questions becomes higher, the result of the first attempt gives me more information. Is there some known result about this?

Comment: Well, there is an obvious $n+1$ step method:  on the first pass, just answer the first question, on the second answer the first two, and so on.

Comment: Even assuming you must answer every question, a slight modification gets you a solution in $n+1$ steps for any $n$:  Answer each question T at step $1$, and then at each succeeding step switch one answer at a time from T to F.  It seems like there should be a way to improve upon that bound, but I don't immediately see one.

Comment: @RobertShore   $n+1$ is not optimal.  For $n=3$, guessing $TTT$ gives you the number of Trues, one of $0,1,2,3$.  If $3$ you are done.  If $0$ you know the answer is $FFF$.  $1$ and $2$ are effectively the same so suppose it is $1$.  So the test is one of $TFF, FTF, FFT$.  Now guess $TF-$  The possible scores are then $2, 0, 1$ so you are done in $3$ steps.  (assuming you can leave things blank, though maybe it's easy to modify that as well).

Comment: @lulu Actually I did not think of not answering some questions!

Comment: As @RobertShore  suggests, that may not be needed.  My method for solving $n=3$ in three steps has you leaving a blank...I haven't thought about ways to remove that.

Comment: if you cannot leave blanks, a simple parity argument shows that 3 steps are not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, off the top of my head.

Let there be $n$ questions.

a) Answer all questions false. You will score $m$ where $0 \le m \le n$. If $m = n$, job done.

b) Answer all questions false except q1, answer true. If your score is $m - 1$, you know that you answered right on a), so q1 is false. If your score is $m + 1$, you know that you answered wrong on a) but right on b), so q1 is true.

c) Answer all questions false except:

i) q1, with either true or false according to which one is correct

ii) q2, which you answer true. And again, this will be either one more or one less than the score when you answered the other way (taking the correct score of q1 into account). And so you can work out whether q2 is true or false.

d) Now you can do the same with Q3, until all answers are correct.

You will get them all correct after at most $n$ passes through the exam.

There may be further shortcuts you can make. But this will do as a start.

Comment: isn't that $n+1$ steps at most, instead of $n$?

Comment: indeed, with this algorithm you _know_ the right answers in $n$ steps, but you may need one more to get a perfect score.

Comment: yeah probably...